# Jasmine: Use expect within loops

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to be able to test an array of cartesian coordinate objects in jasmine. I don't want to make a boatload of tests that will clog up my result screen. I just want to assert that each coordinate in the array is assigned correctly.

```
var i = 0;
for(var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
   for(var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
         expect(coords[i].x).toBe(x);
         expect(coords[i].y).toBe(y);
         ++i;
   }
 }
```

However when I do this my test runner claims there are no expectations.

Comment: Since `i` it is not initialized in your sample code it should be `undefined` at the moment of use.

Answer (score 0):

is the test in `describe`&`it` blocks?

```
describe('coords', function(){
  it('coords[0] matches every x in width and y in height', function(){
    var i = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
       for(var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
             expect(coords[i].x).toBe(x);
             expect(coords[i].y).toBe(y);
             ++i;
       }
     }
  })
})
```

Comment: I am fairly 100% certain it is.

Comment: i dunno, are width and height defined?

Comment: you do realize btw that `coords[0].x` and `coords[0].y` is not gonna change in your loops? plz post the context

Comment: The question really is, can I use expect that way it is used in that block you posted? Mine is literally written just like that, and the command line Jasmine says there are no expectations in the spec, but when I take them out of the loop it works.

Comment: @Breedly dunno. works for me with jasmine-node 1.14.3: https://gist.github.com/plato-cambrian/ca76cc268d4c8ec00f79